# Activity log only shows [Name] 'read an article' without a link

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-opengraph

We're building a site that publishes read actions to a users timeline. In testing, if a user goes to their activity log (https://www.facebook.com/[username]/allactivity), it sometimes shows up as just

- [User] read an article

Without any associated link. See picture below:

[image]

Anyone know what the issue could be?

Answer (score 0):

Testing suggests that this happens when there is no og:image meta data in the page.